# Visual Studio 2012 Search Scope

Tags: visual-studio-2012

[image]

*Visual Studio 2012 Quick Find Dialog*

**Is there a shortcut, or a way to make one, for changing search scope in Visual Studio 2012?**

The new quick search dialog was redesigned, and it is very clunky to get to search scope via the tab key, as the initial keyboard focus is in the first textbox and the scope dropdown was moved relatively far away.

In Visual Studio 2010, it was as simple as hitting the tab key once and you're there.

[image]

*Visual Studio 2012 Quick Find Dialog*

Comment: If you are just changing the scope because VS doesn't keep your defaults then there is also this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/015611c4-b357-4672-8977-f3ec92f0b808

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mr. President, you can always use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the old search dialog.  Then you can just <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: I suspect this will end up being the best answer. Thank you.

Comment: "Then you can just tab"? 6 years later and you have to hit Tab 6 times to get to the scope.  Sure you can 'just' Shift Tab twice, but that's only marginally better.
The OP asked specifically is there a short cut, I hardly think this is an answer let alone an acceptable one, but OPs decision.
Microsoft is negligent here...

Comment: As of VS2022, this answer is no longer accurate. The "old" dialog now has three checkboxes between the search term and the location. You have to tab four times to reach the search location drop-down.

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio 2015 and 2017, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> moves the focus to the dropdown for scope. I haven't tried other VS versions.

EDIT:

In addition,

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> toggles the whole word option

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> toggles the match case option

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> toggles the regular expressions option

Enter does the search. <kbd>F3</kbd> repeats the last search.

<kbd>CTrl + Enter</kbd> pops out the search options sub menu

These are valid for VS2015 and VS2017